# Custom DropDown using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown button in Flutter that displays items in the following manner. I attempted to implement it, but unfortunately, my efforts were unsuccessful. How can I achieve this? I've also searched for a package that can help with this, but haven't been able to find one.

[image]

my try :

```
class CustomDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomDropdown({super.key});

  @override
  State<CustomDropdown> createState() => _CustomDropdownState();
}

class _CustomDropdownState extends State<CustomDropdown> {
  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6, horizontal: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.grey,
          width: 0.4,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      ),
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          isExpanded: true,
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(
              height: 24, width: 24, dropdownIcon, semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo'),
          iconSize: 24,
          elevation: 16,
          style: GoogleFonts.raleway(
            textStyle: TextStyle(
              color: blackColor,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              dropdownValue = newValue!;
            });
          },
          items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My try result:

[image]
and
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### You can use OverlayPortal to create your custom dropdown menu.

We’ll use OverlayPortal to display the menu on top of the button widget. To control when the menu is shown or hidden, we’ll rely on OverlayPortalController. This class gives us the ability to manage our overlay effectively.

Example:

```
class CustomDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomDropDown({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => CustomDropDownState();
}

class CustomDropDownState extends State<CustomDropDown> {
  final OverlayPortalController _tooltipController = OverlayPortalController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlayPortal(
      controller: _tooltipController,
      overlayChildBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
        return const Positioned(
          bottom: 30,
          left: 30,
          child: MenuWidget() // your custom menu,
        );
      },
      child: ButtonWidget(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: const Text('Button Text'),
      ) // menu button,
    );
  }

  void onTap() {
    _tooltipController.toggle();
  }
}
```

You can find out more in this [article](https://medium.com/snapp-x/creating-custom-dropdowns-with-overlayportal-in-flutter-4f09b217cfce)